# Python - How to request pages from website that uses OpenID

Tags: python, authentication, openid, google-openid

I'm writing a python script that scrapes a website, where the website uses OpenID auth to identify me via google.

Is there a python library that will handle do this for me, or do I need to find out and replicate the steps that my browser already does?

Otherwise, is there some standard way of doing this in some other language?

Comment: Hi there, could you provide a detailed solution if you have any? It's not that obvious to me how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client's perspective, an OpenID login is very similar to any other web-based login. There isn't a defined protocol for the client; it is an ordinary web session that varies based on your OpenID provider. For this reason, I doubt that any such libraries exist. You will probably have to code it yourself.

Comment: Hi there. Would it be possible to get more details? I know how to log on to Gmail with Python and urllib2, but I don't see how logging into eg. StackOverflow is possible using that same account. Thanks.