# How to request pages from website that uses OpenID?

Tags: python, authentication, openid, urllib2

*[This question has been asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330335/python-how-to-request-pages-from-website-that-uses-openid). The accepted answer was probably obvious to both questioner and answerer---but not to me. I have commented on the above question to get more precisions, but there was no response. [I also approached the meta Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/needing-more-info-on-question) for help on how to bring back questions from their grave, and got no answer either.*

The answer to the here above question was:

> From the client's perspective, an OpenID login is very similar to any other web-based login. There isn't a defined protocol for the client; it is an ordinary web session that varies based on your OpenID provider. For this reason, I doubt that any such libraries exist. You will probably have to code it yourself.

I know how to [log onto a website with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414683/how-can-i-log-into-a-website-using-python) already, using the [Urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) module. But that's not enough for me to guess how to authenticate to an OpenID.

I'm actually trying to get [my StackOverflow inbox in json format](https://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine), for which I need to be logged in.

Could someone provide a short intro or a link to a nice tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: PS: I flagged this post already for moderator attention with regard to purposely duplicating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer sums up what others have said below, especially [RedBaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533524/redbaron), plus adding a method I used to get to the StackOverflow Inbox using Google Accounts.*

Using the Tamper Data developer tool of Firefox and logging on to StackOVerflow, one can see that OpenID works this way:

1. StackOverflow requests authentication from a given service (here Google), defined in the posted data;
2. Google Accounts takes over and checks for an already existing cookie as proof of authentication;
3. If no cookie is found, Google requests authentication and sets a cookie;
4. Once the cookie is set, StackOverflow acknowledges authentication of the user.

The above sums up the process, which in reality is more complicated, since many redirects and cookie exchanges occur indeed.

Because reproducing the same process programmatically proved somehow difficult (and that might just be my illiteracy), especially trying to hunt down the URLs to call with all locale specifics etc. I opted for loging on to Google Accounts first, getting a well deserved cookie and then login onto Stackoverflow, which would use the cookie for authentication.

This is done simply using the following Python modules: urllib, urllib2, cookielib and BeautifulSoup.

Here is the (simplified) code, it's not perfect, but it does the trick. The extended version can be found on [Github](https://gist.github.com/1542262).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from getpass import getpass

# Define URLs
google_accounts_url = 'http://accounts.google.com'
authentication_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth'
stack_overflow_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate'
genuwine_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine'

# Build opener
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

def request_url(request):    
    '''
        Requests given URL.
    '''     
    try:
        response = opener.open(request)
    except:
        raise
    return response


def authenticate(username='', password=''):        
    '''
        Authenticates to Google Accounts using user-provided username and password,
        then authenticates to StackOverflow.
    '''
    # Build up headers
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0'
    headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent}

    # Set Data to None
    data = None

    # Build up URL request with headers and data    
    request = urllib2.Request(google_accounts_url, data, headers)
    response = request_url(request)

    # Build up POST data for authentication
    html = response.read()
    dsh = BeautifulSoup(html).findAll(attrs={'name' : 'dsh'})[0].get('value').encode()

    auto = response.headers.getheader('X-Auto-Login')

    follow_up = urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(auto)).split('continue=')[-1]

    galx = jar._cookies['accounts.google.com']['/']['GALX'].value

    values = {'continue' : follow_up,
              'followup' : follow_up,
              'dsh' : dsh,
              'GALX' : galx,
              'pstMsg' : 1,
              'dnConn' : 'https://accounts.youtube.com',
              'checkConnection' : '',
              'checkedDomains' : '',
              'timeStmp' : '',
              'secTok' : '',
              'Email' : username,
              'Passwd' : password,
              'signIn' : 'Sign in',
              'PersistentCookie' : 'yes',
              'rmShown' : 1}

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)

    # Build up URL for authentication
    request = urllib2.Request(authentication_url, data, headers)
    response = request_url(request)

    # Check if logged in
    if response.url != request._Request__original:
        print '\n Logged in :)\n'
    else:
        print '\n Log in failed :(\n'

    # Build OpenID Data    
    values = {'oauth_version' : '',
              'oauth_server' : '',
              'openid_username' : '',
              'openid_identifier' : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'}

    data = urllib.urlencode(values)

    # Build up URL for OpenID authetication
    request = urllib2.Request(stack_overflow_url, data, headers)
    response = request_url(request)

    # Retrieve Genuwine
    data = None
    request = urllib2.Request(genuwine_url, data, headers)
    response = request_url(request)
    print response.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = raw_input('Enter your Gmail address: ')
    password = getpass('Enter your password: ')
    authenticate(username, password)
```

Comment: Ugh, why HTMLParser and not something like BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: if you think there is a good reason why BeautifulSoup is better than HTMLParser for this purpose, then feel free to explain and modify the answer.

Comment: Two simple function calls vs subclassing and 6 indentation levels

Comment: @ThiefMaster: OK, I will look at BeautifulSoup and edit the answer asap.

Answer (score 11):

Well I myself don't know much about OpenID but your post (and the bounty!!) got me interested.

[This link](http://blogs.oracle.com/bblfish/entry/the_openid_sequence_diagram) tells the exact flow of OpenID authentication sequence (Atleast for v1.0. The new version is 2.0). From what I could make out, the steps would be something like

1. You fetch the login page of stackoverflow that will also provide an option to login using OpenID (As a form field).
2. You send ur openID  which is actually a form of uri and NOT username/email(If it is Google profile it is your profile ID)
3. Stackoverflow will then connect to your ID provider (in this case google) and send you a redirect to google login page and another link to where you should redirect later (lets say *a*)
4. You can login to the google provided page conventionally (using POST method from Python)
5. Google provides a cryptographic token (Not pretty sure about this step) in return to your login request
6. You send the new request to *a* with this token.
7. Stackoverflow will contact google with this token. If authenticity established, it will return a session ID
8. Later requests to STackOverflow should have this session ID
9. No idea about logging out!!

[This link](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) tells about various responses in OpenID and what they mean. So maybe it will come in handy when your code your client.

Links from the wiki page [OpenID Explained](http://openidexplained.com/use)

EDIT: Using Tamper Data Add on for Firefox, the following sequence of events can be constructed.

1. User sends a request to the SO login page. On entering the openID in the form field  the resulting page sends a 302 redirecting to a google page.
   The redirect URL has a lot of OpenID parameters (which are for the google server). One of them is return_to=https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/?s=some_value.
2. The user is presented with the google login page. On login there are a few 302's which redirect the user around in google realm.
3. Finally a 302 is received which redirects user to stackoverflow's page specified in *'return_to'* earlier
4. During this entire series of operation a lot of cookie's have been generated which must be stored correctly
5. On accessing the SO page (which was 302'd by google), the SO server processes your request and in the response header sends a field "Set-Cookie" to set cookies named gauth and usr with a value along with another 302 to stackoverflow.com. This step completes your login
6. Your client simply stores the cookie usr
7. You are logged in as long as you remeber to send the Cookie usr with any request to SO.
8. You can now request your inbox just remeber to send the usr cookie with the request.

I suggest you start coding your python client and study the responses carefully. In most cases it  will be a series of 302's with minimal user intervention (except for filling out your Google username and password and allowing the site page).

However to make it easier, you could just login to SO using your browser, copy all the cookie values and make a request using urllib2 with the cookie values set.

Of course in case you log out on the browser, you will have to login again and change the cookie value in your python program.

Comment: OK, so I log in to StackOverflow, which redirects me to the login page of eg. Google, which, once logged in, redirects me  back to SO again.
But which URL do you request then to log in to SO?
Normally, you request a URL, which sends you a 301 Error, and then you get the authentication headers, then you add the scheme and realm to the request header, together with username and password.
Now if I request http://stackoverflow.com or http://stackoverflow.com/users/login, I don't get any 301 Error in the first place.

Comment: I think that once you log into your google account, it should send a redirect back to SO (After successful  authentication and allow the site page that is). The redirect URL should have a parameter that contains the crypto token generated by Google for SO. Once you redirect to that SO page, the SO server processes the token and if found to be correct sets a cookie for the rest of your session. Then you are logged into SO. You can request any page from SO as long as you send the cookie with the request and SO will serve that page back to you.

Comment: Using firefox I detect that the following page is accessed after I login to the google account.
http://stackauth.com/auth/global/write?authToken=SomeValue.
Now whether google redirects to this site or SO has in the earlier communication told the browser to redirect to this link once auth is complete that I don't know.
You should probably parse the response of each request and analyze it so that you can find the missing link (Lack of 301 response that is)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response, I'll play around with it and eventually post working code.

Comment: I've looked into it with tamper data. I am wondering: is it necessary to use redirects when authenticating programmatically? Or should I simply log in to google accounts, store relevant cookies and then use these cookies to log on to SE?

Comment: If you want a long lasting solution, then probably you should program everything (including redirects). Otherwise for short cut, you could store the cookies. Personally I would recommend taking the long road. Handling redirects maybe tricky (especially in case of google which authenticates you into youtube etc. at the same time) but you should look for a solution there

Comment: I'd highly suggest you to create your own OpenID provider for such a purpose. Most OpenID-powered sites allow you to enter a custom URL instead of clicking a google/yahoo/whatever button. Then you still need to implement the openid things but don't have to care about login cookies etc. for the openid provider.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: do you have any documentation for this suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is close to archeology, digging a post that's two years old, but I just wrote a new enhanced version of the code from the validated answer, so I thought it may be cool to share it here, as this question/answers has been a great help for me to implement that.

So, here's what's different:

- it uses the new `requests` library that is an enhancement over `urllib2` ;
- it supports authenticating using google's and stackexchange's openid provider.
- it is way shorter and simpler to read, though it has less printouts

here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import urllib
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def get_google_auth_session(username, password):
    session = requests.Session()
    google_accounts_url = 'http://accounts.google.com'
    authentication_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth'
    stack_overflow_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate'

    r = session.get(google_accounts_url)
    dsh = BeautifulSoup(r.text).findAll(attrs={'name' : 'dsh'})[0].get('value').encode()
    auto = r.headers['X-Auto-Login']
    follow_up = urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(auto)).split('continue=')[-1]
    galx = r.cookies['GALX']

    payload = {'continue' : follow_up,
               'followup' : follow_up,
               'dsh' : dsh,
               'GALX' : galx,
               'pstMsg' : 1,
               'dnConn' : 'https://accounts.youtube.com',
               'checkConnection' : '',
               'checkedDomains' : '',
               'timeStmp' : '',
               'secTok' : '',
               'Email' : username,
               'Passwd' : password,
               'signIn' : 'Sign in',
               'PersistentCookie' : 'yes',
               'rmShown' : 1}

    r = session.post(authentication_url, data=payload)

    if r.url != authentication_url: # XXX
        print "Logged in"
    else:
        print "login failed"
        sys.exit(1)

    payload = {'oauth_version' : '',
               'oauth_server' : '',
               'openid_username' : '',
               'openid_identifier' : ''}
    r = session.post(stack_overflow_url, data=payload)
    return session

def get_so_auth_session(email, password):
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get('http://stackoverflow.com/users/login')
    fkey = BeautifulSoup(r.text).findAll(attrs={'name' : 'fkey'})[0]['value']

    payload = {'openid_identifier': 'https://openid.stackexchange.com',
               'openid_username': '',
               'oauth_version': '',
               'oauth_server': '',
               'fkey': fkey,
               }
    r = session.post('http://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate', allow_redirects=True, data=payload)
    fkey = BeautifulSoup(r.text).findAll(attrs={'name' : 'fkey'})[0]['value']
    session_name = BeautifulSoup(r.text).findAll(attrs={'name' : 'session'})[0]['value']

    payload = {'email': email,
               'password': password,
               'fkey': fkey,
               'session': session_name}

    r = session.post('https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login/submit', data=payload)
    # check if url changed for error detection
    error = BeautifulSoup(r.text).findAll(attrs={'class' : 'error'})
    if len(error) != 0:
        print "ERROR:", error[0].text
        sys.exit(1)
    return session

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prov = raw_input('Choose your openid provider [1 for StackOverflow, 2 for Google]: ')
    name = raw_input('Enter your OpenID address: ')
    pswd = getpass('Enter your password: ')
    if '1' in prov:
        so = get_so_auth_session(name, pswd)
    elif '2' in prov:
        so = get_google_auth_session(name, pswd)
    else:
        print "Error no openid provider given"

    r = so.get('http://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine')
    print r.json()
```

the code is also available as a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/guyzmo/5730750)

HTH

Comment: and I've published a project using that to connect to stackoverflow (and the chat) using a command line tool: http://github.com/guyzmo/pystackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement cookies on any "login" page, in Python you use [cookiejar](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects). For example:

```
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
myopener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
#myopener now supports cookies.
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple script that logins to stackoverflow.com using Mozilla Firefox cookies. It's not entirely automated, because you need to login manually, but it's all i managed to do.

Scipt is actual for latest versions of FF ( i'm using 8.0.1 ), but you need to get latest sqlite dll, because default one that comes with python 2.7 can't open DB. You can get it here: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3070900.zip

```
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import cookielib
import os
import sqlite3
import re
from time import sleep

#login in Firefox. Must be default browser. In other cases log in manually
webbrowser.open_new('http://stackoverflow.com/users/login')

#wait for user to log in
sleep(60)

#Process profiles.ini to get path to cookies.sqlite
profile = open(os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],'Mozilla','Firefox','profiles.ini'), 'r').read()

COOKIE_DB = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],'Mozilla','Firefox','Profiles',re.findall('Profiles/(.*)\n',profile)[0],'cookies.sqlite')
CONTENTS = "host, path, isSecure, expiry, name, value"

#extract cookies for specific host
def get_cookies(host):
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()   
    con = sqlite3.connect(COOKIE_DB)
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT {c} FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%{h}%'".format(c=CONTENTS, h=host)
    cur.execute(sql)
    for item in cur.fetchall():
        c = cookielib.Cookie(0, item[4], item[5],
            None, False,
            item[0], item[0].startswith('.'), item[0].startswith('.'),
            item[1], False,
            item[2],
            item[3], item[3]=="",
            None, None, {})
        cj.set_cookie(c)
    return cj

host = 'stackoverflow'

cj = get_cookies(host)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

response = opener.open('http://stackoverflow.com').read()

# if username in response - Auth successful
if 'Stanislav Golovanov' in response:
    print 'Auth successful'
```

Comment: You are probably aware of the flaws in this code, but I mention them so that everybody knows. 1. Not portable (works on Windows only). 2. Doesn't work if there is more than 1 firefox profile 3. Doesn't work if user doesn't log in within 60 seconds 4. Have to wait even if logged in quicker than 60 seconds 5. Useless server-side